# Tricky limits question

Tags: limits

The following question is a tricky one:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x+1)^{2/3}-(x-1)^{2/3}}{(x+2)^{2/3}-(x-2)^{2/3}}$$

I can actually get an answer by employing the identity $a^3 -b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$

However its very fiddly and messy and i am wondering if there is a more efficient way of getti

Comment: MathJax please :)

Comment: Where's the trick?

Comment: Error 404: Trickiness not found.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't apply $a^3-b^3 = \ldots $ identity, but rather $a^2-b^2 = \ldots$ one.

Comment: No because then you get something to the power of 4/3 which is not easily solvable. By using a^3 - b^3 you two square terms in the numerator which when expanded can provide us with an answer.

Comment: Suit yourself $ $

Comment: If my post (or any other posts from below) fully answers your question, do not hesitate to mark it as such. I've noticed that you don't really do that, based on your other questions, which is not a good practice here on SE.

Answer (score 6):

First, do a simple substitution $t = \frac 1x$, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {x^{\frac 23}\left [\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^{\frac 23}-\left(1-\frac 1x\right)^{\frac 23}\right ]}{x^{\frac 23}\left [\left(1+\frac 2x\right)^{\frac 23}-\left(1-\frac 2x\right)^{\frac 23}\right ]} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac {(1+t)^{\frac 23} - (1-t)^{\frac 23}}{(1+2t)^{\frac 23}-(1-2t)^{\frac 23}} = \\
= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac {1+\frac 23t+o(t) - 1 + \frac 23t + o(t)}{1+\frac 43t+o(t)-1+\frac43t+o(t)} = \frac 12
$$

Answer (score 2):

When $x$ gets large, you only care about the next terms in the series in $\frac 1x$ that don't cancel.  So
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x+1)^{2/3}-(x-1)^{2/3}}{(x+2)^{2/3}-(x-2)^{2/3}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac 1x)^{2/3}-(1-\frac 1x)^{2/3}}{(1+\frac 2x)^{2/3}-(1-\frac 2x)^{2/3}}$$
The leading terms ($1$s) will cancel in the subtraction, but the next terms will not.  Do a power series expansion in $\frac 1x$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

As in Kastner's solution, we let $x=1/h$ and evaluate the limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(x+1)^{2/3}-(x-1)^{2/3}}{(x+2)^{2/3}-(x-2)^{2/3}}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(1+h)^{2/3}-(1-h)^{2/3}}{(1+2h)^{2/3}-(1-2h)^{2/3}}\\\\
&=\frac12\underbrace{\color{blue}{\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{(1+h)^{2/3}-(1-h)^{2/3}}{2h}\right)}}_{\text{Symmetric Derivative}}\underbrace{\color{red}{\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{4h}{(1+2h)^{2/3}-(1-2h)^{2/3}}\right)}}_{\text{Reciprocal Symmetric Derivative}}\tag 1\\\\
&=\frac12\color{blue}{\left.\left(\frac{dx^{2/3}}{dx}\right)\right|_{x=1}}\color{red}{\left.\left(\frac{1}{\frac{dx^{2/3}}{dx}}\right)\right|_{x=1}}\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

---

> Note that we have recognized the the limits in $(1)$ as the [Symmetric Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) of $f(x)=x^{2/3}$ evaluated at $x=1$.  We did not need to evaluate these since we have $f'(1)/f'(1)=1$ for $f'(1)\ne 0$.

Comment: This was quite a trick.  I learnt something new and +1 for that.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I had never seen this approach before.   After looking at this for a moment, I saw the light.  Thank you as always my friend!  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

If you want a generalization
$$x^{1-\frac{a}{b}}[(x+k)^{\frac{a}{b}}-(x-k)^{\frac{a}{b}}]\to 2k\frac{a}{b}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the omnipresent l'Hospital's rule:

$L=\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac{(x+1)^{2/3}\left(1-\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2/3}\right)}{(x+2)^{2/3}\left(1-\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)^{2/3}\right)}=
\underbrace{\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac{(x+1)^{2/3}}{(x+2)^{2/3}}}_{=1}\cdot \lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac{1-\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2/3}}{1-\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)^{2/3}}\stackrel{l'H}=
\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac{-\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{-1/3}\cdot \frac{2}{(x+1)^2}}{-\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)^{-1/3}\cdot \frac{4}{(x+2)^2}}=
\frac{1}{2}.$